# How to incorporate meaningful and purposeful technology into math lessons.

Tags: education

A big part of today's learning is centered around technology. As a math teacher, I sometimes find it difficult to incorporate meaningful and purposeful technology into my lessons. Are there any things that you've tried in the past that you think would be beneficial or that you've felt has worked well? I am a teacher at the middle school and high school level, so I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: We have a Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a far more appropriate post on [matheducators.se]

Answer (score 2):

There are many many ways to do this.  How to do it depends on the level of math that you're teaching.  But looking at the Ted Talk by Dan Meyer is probably a great way to start:

https://www.ted.com/talks/dan_meyer_math_curriculum_makeover?language=en

My preference is to teach math with programming.  There are very simple things you can do.  Design a computer and have that computer perform a Taylor series calculation of sin(x), cos(x), exp(x).  Have your students find the roots of polynomials.  Have your students determine the minimum of interesting functions in several different ways.  Have your students solve linear systems.

Here is a website of a high school class teaching students to do some of those things:  http://nicholasdwork.com/teaching/si2016/session2/